# "This ip site or mobile application is not authorized to use this api key"

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I use this https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary library and my code is in below;

```
 GoogleDirection.withServerKey("MyApiKey")
            .from(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(work.getAxCor()), Double.parseDouble(work.getAyCor())))
            .to(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(work.getBxCor()), Double.parseDouble(work.getByCor())))
            .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
                    if(direction.isOK()) {

                        Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                        Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);
                        Info distanceInfo = leg.getDistance();
                        Info durationInfo = leg.getDuration();
                        distance = distanceInfo.getText();
                        duration = durationInfo.getText();

                    } else {

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
```

But i get a mistake ""This ip site or mobile application is not authorized to use this api key"". Map is shown. There is no problem on map. Geocoding, Geolocation and places Api's are enable. Thanks.

Comment: Just co confirm you followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key? It says `During development and testing, you can register a project for testing purposes in the Google Cloud Platform Console and use a generic, unrestricted API key. When you are ready to move your app or website into production, register a separate project for production, create a server-restricted API key, and add the key to your application.` Did you create a server restricted API key instead of testing one? If yes, then you might need to specify the allowed IP's etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Yes i have two seperated api keys and both work correctly with Google Maps. But do not work with this library unfortunately.

Comment: If you see their `AndroidManifest` sample app file, they have defined it there as well. Maybe you need to change there as well : https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml . If that doesn't work, the developer might be able to help better, so maybe open a issue on the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Directions API it's a [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/web-service-best-practices#WebServices) and bundle restrictions can't be applied.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) you can either use a proxy, obfuscate the key or certificate pinning.